# Transform rows in columns by Day Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, rows

I have this table

```
|ID | day_name   |        day_date     |
  1   Monday     2018-01-08 00:00:00.000
  2   Monday     2018-01-15 00:00:00.000
  3   Monday     2018-01-22 00:00:00.000
  4   Monday     2018-01-29 00:00:00.000
 10   Tuesday    2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
 11   Tuesday    2018-01-23 00:00:00.000
 12   Tuesday    2018-01-30 00:00:00.000
```

I want to rotate the rows to columns so the result set is like this:

```
|        Monday            |       Tuesday           |
2018-01-08 00:00:00.000     2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
2018-01-15 00:00:00.000     2018-01-23 00:00:00.000
2018-01-22 00:00:00.000     2018-01-30 00:00:00.000
2018-01-29 00:00:00.000
```

I've tried something but the results are not as expected:

```
WITH dayz AS
(
    SELECT day_name, day_date,
    [rn] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day_name ORDER BY day_date)
    FROM ISP_Cloud_DaysFromSession
)
SELECT 
    day_name,
     MondayDates = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  TuesdayyDates = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column4 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column5 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column6 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column7 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column8 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END),
  Column9 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN day_date ELSE NULL END)
  FROM
  dayz
  GROUP BY day_name
```

Any ideas how to transform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't far off, but you're grouping by the wrong thing. The Row Number is what you want in each row, but you've defined it as your columns

```
WITH Days AS
    (SELECT day_name,
            day_date,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day_name ORDER BY day_date) AS [rn]
     FROM dbo.ISP_Cloud_DaysFromSession)
SELECT MAX(CASE day_name WHEN 'Monday' THEN day_date END) AS Monday,
       MAX(CASE day_name WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN day_date END) AS Tuesday
FROM Days
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `row_number` and `pivot`:

```
WITH Days AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day_name ORDER BY day_date) rr
    , day_name, day_date
  FROM ISP_Cloud_DaysFromSession
)
SELECT [Monday], [Tuesday]
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Days
) AS SOURCE
PIVOT (
  MAX (day_date)
  FOR day_name IN ([Monday], [Tuesday])
) AS pivotable
```